# RemoteCommand with percent signs doesn't work

Tags: ssh, quoting, escape-characters, ssh-config

The following command

```
tmux new -A -s $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
```

works and starts `tmux` with a session, named after current datetime (as expected).

But if I put the same in `ssh` config

```
RemoteCommand tmux new -A -s $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
```

it says

```
percent_expand: unknown key %Y
```

why and how to fix?

---

Apparently, `ssh` tries to [expand percent sign](https://www.dtucker.net/openssh/percent_expand_opts.html). How to disable/escape this expansion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%%` where you want a literal `%`. This is extremely common: in most syntaxes that have a single escape character, doubling that character yields the literal character. For example `\\` to match a literal backslash in a regular expression, `\\` to get a literal backslash character in a shell unquoted or double-quoted word, `%%` to get a literal percent sign in `printf` output, etc.

```
RemoteCommand tmux new -A -s $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
```

The summary table you found didn't bother to list `%%`, but [the OpenSSH manual does](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#TOKENS).

If you wanted a literal percent sign in the output of `date` (for whatever reason) you'd double the `%` for `date`: `date +%Y%m%d%%%H%M%S` puts a percent sign between the date and the time. In an SSH remote command, you'd need to double once for `date` and once for SSH, so 4 `%` would stand for one: `RemoteCommand tmux new -A -s $(date +%Y%m%d%%%%%H%M%S)`.

Comment: Ya, I did this, but hateful that doc was silent :D